# Position Absolute and Z-Index Not Stacking Over Other Elements

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I am having a very novice issue with positioning.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I can't get the blue section at the bottom of my page to be positioned on top of all other elements with absolute positioning and z-index.

It seems like the div with the image is causing the issue but i'm not sure why. The layout logic seems simple.

I have a div on the left with a class of 'left-frame' that acts as a container for the left content. This div is styled as follows:

```
    .left-frame
    {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 45vw;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
```

*(I also don't understand why I had to specify the vertical align. Without it the main image div and the left frame div were misaligned, but that's a separate question)*

The right side of the layout is just a div with a class of main-image that has an img element inside and is meant to take up the rest of the screen. Styled as follows:

```
    .main-image
    {
       width: 54vw;
       height: 100vh;
       display: inline-block;

    }
    .main-image img
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

Finally, the bottom blue part is supposed to end up styled as a banner with contact information sitting on top of all other elements. Currently it is styled as follows:

```
    .contacts__body
    {
        background: var(--main-blue);
        width: 100vw;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

The absolute positioning with z-index is not functioning properly. I know it's something I'm doing wrong but I can't understand why.

Below is the final design I'm trying to re-create for reference.

Also the full code is here in a codepen with different images. https://codepen.io/dansoutar/pen/OJJJmdm?editors=1000

[final shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7QPm.png)

Thanks for any insights.